# Absolute positioned menu couldn't show in fixed header in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hidden, fixed, absolute

HTML and style like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: #AAA;
    }
    .menu {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }

    ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        background: #CCC;
        color: #C00;
    }
    .menu:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
        <a>HOVER~</a>
        <ul><li>SHOW ME!!</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The header is position fixed, and the menu is position absoluted, the simple code works well in my IE8.
But the menus are invisible in online version, seems like the menus are overflowed and hiddened by parent, which should be not.
I tried toggle CSS rules or set z-index, still can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is not the posted code, if you do a fiddle with it, everything works (also in ie). I think the problem (I have it also in ie9) is a style rule in the class: .sub-header. This is your original code:

```
.sub-header {
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,#3B3B3B 0,#2B2B2B 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0%,#3B3B3B),color-stop(100%,#2B2B2B));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,#3B3B3B 0,#2B2B2B 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom,#3B3B3B 0,#2B2B2B 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom,#3B3B3B 0,#2B2B2B 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom,#3B3B3B 0,#2B2B2B 100%);
    /* the following line should be removed, wrong syntax and causes height/display problems */
    *filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startcolorstr=#FF3B3B3B,endcolorstr=#FF2B2B2B)url(0/);
    background: url(http://img.yesneaker.com/img/common/gray-stripe.png) #3B3B3B repeat;
    background: url(http://img.yesneaker.com/img/common/black-circle.png) #222 repeat fixed;
    background: url(http://img.yesneaker.com/img/common/header-bg.png) 50% 0 #2B2B2B repeat;
}
```

The problem is the filter (first there is a mistake at the end of the line - the url), second, there are a few issues with gradient filter and the height of elements - try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Genius~! Thank you~! I really forgot about the filters, they are experimental~ My fault~